# Keras model, getting the same loss even after changing the weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I am trying to implement a meta learining for the omniglot data set but something is not right.

Here is the code:

```
def get_siamese_model(input_shape):
    """
        Model architecture based on the one provided in: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~gkoch/files/msc-thesis.pdf
    """

    # Define the tensors for the two input images
    left_input = Input(input_shape)
    right_input = Input(input_shape)

    # Convolutional Neural Network
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
                   kernel_initializer=initialize_weights, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu',
                     kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid',
                   kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3),
                   kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,bias_initializer=initialize_bias))

    # Generate the encodings (feature vectors) for the two images
    encoded_l = model(left_input)
    encoded_r = model(right_input)

#     # Add a customized layer to compute the absolute difference between the encodings
#     L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
#     L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

#     # Add a dense layer with a sigmoid unit to generate the similarity score
#     prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',bias_initializer=initialize_bias)(L1_distance)

    #Connect the inputs with the outputs
    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=[encoded_l, encoded_r])

    # return the model
    return siamese_net

def forward(model, x1, x2):

    return model.call([x1,x2]) 

model = get_siamese_model((105, 105, 1))

test_loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as test_tape:
    test_tape.watch(model.trainable_weights)
    test_tape.watch(test_loss)

    x, y = get_batch(32)
    x1 = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(x[0]), dtype=tf.float32)
    x2 = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(x[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
    y1 = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(y), dtype=tf.float32)
    train_loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.0)

    with tf.GradientTape() as train_tape:
        train_tape.watch(model.trainable_weights)
        train_tape.watch(train_loss)

        train_loss = contrastive_loss(forward(model, x1, x2), y1)

    gradients = train_tape.gradient(train_loss, model.trainable_weights)
    old_weights = model.get_weights()

    model.set_weights([w - 0.01 * g for w, g in zip(model.trainable_weights, gradients)])

    test_loss = contrastive_loss(forward(model, x1, x2), y1)

    model.set_weights(old_weights)    

print(train_loss)
print(test_loss)
```

Results:

```
tf.Tensor(8.294627, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(8.294627, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Why am I getting the same loss? As you can see the weights are changed but output is the same. Changing the weights should result in a different output which should result in a different loss? Maybe forward changes the weights again?

Comment: I have showed my model definition

Comment: Ok....if you try to use `apply_gradients` instead of doing it manually and it still doesn't work, the problem might be your initializers and saturation of the sigmoid.

Comment: OK, I will try and see

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a crossentropy loss function.  The loss you are seeing (8.2...) is essentially the maximum possible loss which means there’s an overflow in the loss calculation.  This can commonly happen for example if you predictions are outside of the range 0-1 or if your if you are predicting exactly 0.

Comment: I am currently not using crossentropy but contrastive_loss function however, maybe it is the maximum possible loss